# Dates and Times displaying the wrong date in view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, timestamp

I have a Rails 3.2.11 application running Ruby 1.9.3p362.

In one of the models I am listing all calls that are in the table:

```
@calls = Call.all
```

This correctly outputs all calls using the following code in the view:

```
<% @calls.each do |call| %>
    <%= call.time.strftime("%d %b. %Y -  %H:%M") %></td>
<% end %>
```

The most recent timestamp in the table is 2013-01-12 14:34:00. Everything works correctly using the above code. The latest call shows at the bottom of the table like this:

```
12 Jan. 2013 - 14:34
```

However, when I try and reverse the order and sort the calls by time with then newest on top the timestamp messes up:

```
@calls = Call.order('time DESC')
```

Puts the following timestamp at the top:

```
31 Dec. 2013 - 19:27
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? As soon as I add the order filter it messes the timestamps up.

Comment: have you tried @calls = Call.all.reverse ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but I think the following should give you the timestamps in descending order

```
 @calls = Call.all.reverse
```

Comment: This works until I try and add any further conditions `@calls = Call.all.reverse.where(:destination => ["123", "456", "789"]).page(params[:page]).per_page(25)`

Comment: you can add the conditions on Call.all and then reverse the result

Comment: Hmm, it works until I add in the pagination. `@calls = Call.all.where(:destination => ["123", "456", "789"]).reverse` works but `@calls = Call.all.where(:destination => ["123", "456", "789"]).page(params[:page]).per_page(25).reverse` does not.

Comment: How about: @calls = Call.all.where(:destination => ["123", "456", "789"]).reverse.page(params[:page]).per_page(25)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   @calls = Call.descend_by_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this query:

```
@calls = Call.all.where(:destination => ['123']).desc(:time)
```

where `:time` is name of attribute meant for sorting.

If you are sorting using `updated_at` attribute which is ubiquitous in every model table, then you can replace `:time` by `:updated_at`.